# Get original URL referer with the condition

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form

I need to collect data through a contact form and track customer referrals. I am creating a tag for the form, but I need it to be filled only if there was a transition from a referral that contained `partner`

my code

```
// Original Referrer 
function wpshore_set_session_values() 
{
    if (!session_id()) 
    {
        session_start();
    }

    if (!isset($_SESSION['OriginalRef'])) 
    {
        $_SESSION['OriginalRef'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
    }

    if (!isset($_SESSION['LandingPage'])) 
    {
        $_SESSION['LandingPage'] = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; 
    }
      

}
add_action('init', 'wpshore_set_session_values');

/// 
function getRefererPage3( $form_tag ){  

$partner = array (
  '/partner/',
);
$parts = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (!empty($parts['path']) || in_array($parts['path'], $partner)){   //this row. I doubt how it should be
    if ( $form_tag['name'] == 'referer-page3' ) {   
    $form_tag['values'][] = $_SESSION['LandingPage'];
}
}
return $form_tag;
}

if ( !is_admin() ) {
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_tag', 'getRefererPage3' );
}
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Also your usage of session will cause problems for you.

Comment: @HowardE I marked a line that I doubt. I want to get the value only when the original link has `partner`

Comment: `$parts['path']` is the _full_ path, so unless that was just `/partner/` in the referrer URL and _nothing else_, you won't find a match with `in_array`. If you don't need to check against multiple possible strings, do a simple string search instead.

Comment: @CBroe Can you tell me what is meant by `simple string search instead`? Do you mean something like this `if (strpos($parts, 'partner') !== true) {`

Comment: I am just talking about checking whether one string _contains_ another. (And if you don't know how to do that in PHP yet, please research it.)

Comment: @CBroe  Do you mean something like this `if (strpos($parts, 'partner') !== true) {`

Comment: `strpos` never returns true. You need to use `!== false` when you want to verify that it did _not_ find a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. Maybe this solution will help anyone in the future.

```
function getRefererPage3( $form_tag ){  
    if (strpos($_SESSION['LandingPage'], 'partner') !== false) { 
        if ( $form_tag['name'] == 'referer-page3 ) {    
        $form_tag['values'][] = $_SESSION['LandingPage'];
    }
    }
    return $form_tag;
    }
   if ( !is_admin() ) {
    add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_tag', 'getRefererPage3' );
    }
```